# Scikit-Learn's Perceptron training accuracy below 100% though data linearly separable

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, perceptron

I'm using `sklearn`'s [perceptron](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html) on the `wine` dataset and I expected to see the training accuracy at 100% since I know the classes are linearly separable (shown below). Code:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
import numpy as np

# import data
wine = datasets.load_wine()
X = wine['data']
y = wine['target']
X_binary = X[y != 2].copy() # only keep 2 classes
y_binary = y[y != 2].copy() # only keep 2 classes

# fit, etc.
perceptron = Perceptron()
perceptron.fit(X_binary, y_binary);
np.all(perceptron.predict(X_binary) == y_binary) # False
```

Anyone know why the final line isn't `True`?

Showing that the data is linearly separable:

```
beta = np.array(
      [-0.03733196, -0.00865585, -0.07756126,  0.00770558, -0.00001171,
        0.01579195, -0.01308789,  0.01526745,  0.00937851, -0.00191233,
        0.00859206, -0.0352664 , -0.00013141])

print(max((X_binary @ beta)[y_binary == 0]))
print(min((X_binary @ beta)[y_binary == 1]))
# max for the 0 case is less than the min for the 1 case
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Not yet ... what values did you get?  You failed to print the intermediate items causing the problem.  Please review [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Prune apologies, which intermediate items? The only thing causing the problem is the line `np.all(perceptron.predict(X_binary) == y_binary)` which returns False. Is there something else I should include? Thanks

Comment: What are the values you're comparing?

Comment: I'm comparing the true outcome variables (`y_binary`) with the fitted values from the perceptron (`perceptron.predict(X_binary)`). I would expect these all to be equal.

Comment: I asked for the *values*, not the variables.  Again, please follow the MRE description.

Comment: I can't fit all the values in a comment but `perceptron.predict(X_binary)` starts off with `array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,...` while `y_binary` is all 0s for a while and then all 1s. You can also see this by running the first chunk of code. 

Also, MRE says to be minimal, complete, and reproducible... I would think my question is all three?

Comment: Your critical information belongs in the question, clearly formatted, not in a comment.  Since the values are too long to fit into a comment, I am pretty certain that the test case is *not* minimal.  Simply hard-code a small list of `X` and `y` values; drop the `datasets` loading, as the problem isn't there.  If you're still confused, try looking up best practices for how to report a bug.

Comment: It's hard to hard-code numbers that will work. I stumbled upon this set by accident. And I figured I included the important information by noting that the two were not the same. Thank you for looking.